# Objective C Application Runs Out of Memory in long loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, out-of-memory, nsautoreleasepool

I am building a Mac Application with Xcode that has a very long lasting loop in one of the methods. I use the loop inside an Autoreleasing Pool (@autoreleasepool) but my app still eventually runs out of memory.

My application executes a thread in the background and uses NSDirectoryEnumerator that runs a system wide file search and changes every icon (using NSWorkspace) of every file on the entire system and constantly update a textfield with the file path changed. This is obviously why its running out of memory but I want to know how I can stop it from using up memory without freeing it.

Here is my source code:

```
NSImage *newFileIcon = ...;
NSImage *newFolderIcon = ...;
NSString *sourcePath = [@"/" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *directoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sourcePath];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLIsDirectoryKey];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:newFolderIcon forFile:[directoryURL path] options:NSExcludeQuickDrawElementsIconCreationOption];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtURL:directoryURL includingPropertiesForKeys:keys options:0 errorHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {return YES;}];
@autoreleasepool {
    for (NSURL *url in enumerator) {
        NSError *error;
        NSNumber *isDirectory = nil;
        if (![url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error!"); // File Error
        } else if (![isDirectory boolValue]) {
            // Set File Icon
            [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:newFileIcon forFile:[url path] options:NSExcludeQuickDrawElementsIconCreationOption];
            // Update Status TextField
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.statusField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Changed File : \n%@", url.path]];});
            // Log File Changed
            NSLog(@"Changed File : %@", [url path]);
        } else if ([isDirectory boolValue]) {
            // Set Folder Icon
            [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:newFolderIcon forFile:[url path] options:NSExcludeQuickDrawElementsIconCreationOption];
            // Update Status TextField
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                               [self.statusField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Changed Folder : \n%@", url.path]];});
            // Log Folder Changed
            NSLog(@"Changed Folder : %@", [url path]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your autorelease pool is encompassing the whole loop; it isn't drained until all files are processed (and all icon images are likely around in RAM until then). Perhaps place it **inside** the loop so it is drained once for every URL...

Comment: Ok thanks ill try that, should I still keep the outter release pool?

Comment: No, I don't think so. But I'm no autorelease pool expert either. And perhaps one pool per round of your loop is overkill, but on the other hance, grouping your URLs in groups of (say) 10 would add complexity to your logic.

Comment: Hmm how do you suggest I make it every 10 in my code?

Comment: Perhaps you can group your URLs in arrays of 10, and put those arrays in a larger array. Then, have an outer loop that lops over the large array, creating and draining the pool each time. Inside that pool, you loop over the inner array (the 10 URLs). But this is prone to add bugs. First, you should try the "overkill" apporach I suggested earlier and see if it fixes your memory outage

Comment: So what do you mean by 'Overkill' if I was make it release for every loop, would it still work alright or what?

Comment: Yes, it should work. But I was thinking that perhaps the performance penalty of creating and draining one autorelease pool per URL would make it too inefficient (slow and processor intensive) -also inelegant-, so once you checked that it solves your problem, you could refactor your code into using less pools

Comment: Ok it will just be easier to make it each url